# Relation between $\lim_{x ‎\to ‎\infty} ‎\frac{f f''}{(f')^2}$ and $‎‏‌‎\lim_{x ‎\to ‎\infty} ‎\frac{f' f'''}{(f'')^2}$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, analysis

> Let assume ‎$‎f ‎\in ‎C^3((0,\infty))‎$‎‎‏ and ‎$‎‎‎f,f',f'' >0‎$. If
>   $$ ‎‎‏‌‎\lim_{x ‎\to ‎\infty} ‎‎\dfrac{f' f'''}{(f'')^2} =‎ c‎ \neq ‎1‎ $$
>   ‏show that
>   $$ \lim_{x ‎\to ‎\infty} ‎‎\dfrac{f f''}{(f')^2} = ‎\dfrac{1}{2-c}. $$

My attempt: By Taylor Theorem we know that:

$$f(x+h)=f(x)+f'(x)h+f''(x) \frac{h^2}{2} + f'''(\xi) \frac{h^3}{6}, \qquad \text{for} \,\,\, \text{some} \qquad \xi \in (x,x+h).$$

Multiplying both sides in $f'(x)$ and dividing by $(f'(x))^2$ we obtain:

$$ \frac{f(x)f(x+h)}{(f'(x))^2}= \Big(\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)} \Big)^2+\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}h+\frac{f(x)f''(x)}{(f'(x))^2} \frac{h^2}{2} + \frac{f(x) f'''(\xi)}{(f'(x))^2} \frac{h^3}{6}.$$

Also, multiplying both sides in $f'(x)$ and dividing by $(f''(x))^2$ we obtain:

$$ \frac{f'(x)f(x+h)}{(f''(x))^2}= \frac{f'(x)f(x)}{(f''(x))^2} + \Big(\frac{f'(x)}{f''(x)} \Big)^2 h +\frac{f'(x)}{f''(x)} \frac{h^2}{2} + \frac{f'(x) f'''(\xi)}{(f''(x))^2} \frac{h^3}{6}.$$

I don't know how to continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the Taylor Theorem as you're trying, note that

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\left(\frac{f'}{f''}\right)' & = \frac{f'(-f''')}{\left(f''\right)^2} + \frac{f''}{f''} \\
& = -\frac{f'(f''')}{\left(f''\right)^2} + 1
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Thus, you have that

$$\frac{f'(f''')}{\left(f''\right)^2} = 1 - \left(\frac{f'}{f''}\right)' \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Similarly, you have

$$\frac{f(f'')}{\left(f'\right)^2} = 1 - \left(\frac{f}{f'}\right)' \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Thus, with the limit you're given of

$$\lim_{x ‎\to ‎\infty} ‎‎\frac{f' f'''}{(f'')^2} =‎ c‎ \neq ‎1‎ \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

and using \eqref{eq2A} you get

$$\lim_{x ‎\to ‎\infty} ‎‎\left(\frac{f'}{f''}\right)' =‎ 1‎ - c \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

I trust you can now proceed on your own to finish the rest of the solution.